# Edit button is not visible in community

Tags: community, lightning-community, partner-communities

I have an edit button on the community record. The button is overwritten by a visualforce page. I enabled the visualforce page for lightning experience and added the button to the proper page layout.

For some reason, the button is not visible in the community.

Could you help me to solve this issue?

Thank you, in advance.
Olga

Answer (score 0):

Based on [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5), overrides to standard Visualforce actions aren't supported which seems to be your case.

> Overrides to standard Visualforce actions such as View, New, Edit, and Delete aren’t supported in sites. These buttons on record detail pages don’t display in sites.

You can use a custom Lightning component to replace standard forms when users click the New or Edit button as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_override_standard_actions.htm&type=5&release=226).